# Android - Set timeout to Loader

Tags: android, timeout, android-loadermanager, android-loader, android-internet

I'm using loaders to handle internet connections and it's working fine. Now I want to control the duration of the connection attempt, in other words to set a timeout.

I'm using the following code:

in `onCreate` method:

```
Uri SearchUri =
                Uri.parse(urlString);

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putParcelable(ARGS_URI, SearchUri);

        // Initialize the Loader.
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_SEARCH,
                args, this);
```

The other methods:

```
    @Override
public Loader<RESTLoader.RESTResponse> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle args) {

    a = args;

    Log.v("TESTING","in OnCreateLoader");
    if (args != null && args.containsKey(ARGS_URI)){

        Log.v("TESTING","in OnCreateLoader, getting communication key");
        Uri action = args.getParcelable(ARGS_URI);

        return new RESTLoader(this, RESTLoader.HTTPVerb.GET,action);
    }



    return null;
}


  @Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<RESTLoader.RESTResponse> loader, RESTLoader.RESTResponse data) {



    int code = data.getCode();
    String json = data.getData();


    if (code == 200){
        Log.v("TESTING","Inside onLoadFinished, code = 200");
    }

    else {
        Log.v("TESTING","Inside onLoadFinished, code != 200");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection Problem", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    // Check to see if we got an HTTP 200 code and have some data.
    if (code == 200 && !json.equals("")) {
    ...
    }
   }
```

So how can I set a timeout on the loader? For instance give a 10 sec duration, if there's no response yet, stop the attempt.

Comment: did you consider using AsyncQeryHandler ? its good for CRUD operations

Comment: @pskink I haven't actually, but I thought to first check whether it's possible with Loaders since I'm using them extensively in my app. It would be a hassle to switch to other methods.

Comment: did you try to call cancelLoad via a delayed Handler Message ?

Comment: @pskink can you please elaborate on that point?

Comment: in your AsyncTaskLoader's constructor or in onStartLoading create a Handler: h = new Handler(this) and then call h.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, tout), in handleMessage method call cancelLoad